# Одновременный одинаковый запрос к PHP скрипту с нескольких разных устройств

Tags: php, post

Я хочу, чтобы php скрипт принимал через POST запрос никнейм, который пользователь хочет создать. Затем, чтобы этот скрипт анализировал обычный текстовый файл на сервере (допустим ReservedNames.txt), и если не находил совпадения, записывал новый никнейм в этот текстовый файл.
Но что, если будут два одновременных запроса с одинаковым никнеймом к одному php скрипту, а соответственно, одному текстовому файлу. Возможно ли такое, чтобы они одновременно анализировали один текстовый файл, и чтобы каждому из них вернулось true, что они могут записать имя в этот текстовый файл, и чтобы там создалос два одинаковых имени.
Я только недавно начл работать с php (а так работаю на c# в unity), и, возможно есть другие варианты (как например работа с базами данных или отправка кода подтверждения на mail). Но меня интересует этот вопрос для понимания, как вообще выполняются php скрипты на сервере.
Спасибо.

Comment: Использование ReservedNames.txt нелогично, для этого есть база данных. Что бы понять как все работает, то посмотрите любой принцип регистрации пользователей, которых множество в интернете

Comment: @Дмитрий, спасибо за ответ. Скорее всего, так и сделаю. Но, в любом случае, хотелось бы знать, что происходит в описанном выше примере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP не работает мультипоточно если это не указано явно в скрипте, так что если прийдут 2 запроса то 2-й будет ждать пока не выполнится первый. А вообще для таких целей существуют базы данных особенно в PHP

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я просто помню, что когда-то где-то видел, что апач может обрабатывать одновременно много запросов. Получается, что в любом случае, это надо указать в php скрипте, если я хочу использовать многопоточность? Там, вроде, говорилось, что надо изменить именно настройки апача.

Comment: Nginx, apache - это уже да. Если надо сделать проверку никнейма то надо уже БД + поле никнейма должно быть уникальным. Потом если приходят одновременно 2 запроса с одинаковым никнеймом на запись в  БД, то 2-й выдаст ошибку которую можно обработать и вывести сообщение что никнейм уже занят.

Comment: Возьмите для начала MySQL и попробуйте с ним поработать и всякие мысли на счет запись в файл резко пропадут. Ну а потом можно уже будет и другие базы посмотреть.